# proving the integral convention $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx + \int_{c}^{b}f(x)dx$ using the epsilon-delta definition

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta, riemann-integration

let $a,b,$ and $c$ be real numbers with $a<c<b$
and function $f$ is integrable in intervals $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$.

Show that the function f is integrable in $[a,b]$ and that

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx + \int_{c}^{b}f(x)dx$

What I have so far:

In the intervals $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$, the function f is integrable. That means the Riemann sum in each interval converges to a real number $I_{i}$, where $i=1,2$, which represents the limit as the absolute value of partition converges to $0$.

How do I combine the 2 aforementioned Riemann sums so that there is a real number $I_{3}$, such that the Riemann sum in $[a,b]$ converges to $I_{3}$?

Comment: A choice of a convenient way to do this depends on how you have already developed the theory. In particular, do you already have the equivalence of Riemann and Darboux integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is integrable, by definition,
\begin{align}I_1+I_2&=\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx+\int_{c}^{b}f(x)dx=\inf_{a=p_0<p_1<\cdots p_k=c}\sum_{i=1}^k \sup_{[p_{i-1},p_i]}f+\inf_{c=q_0<q_1<\cdots p_n=b}\sum_{i=1}^n \sup_{[q_{i-1},q_i]}f.\\
I_3&=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\inf_{a=t_0<t_1<\cdots t_m=b}\sum_{i=1}^k \sup_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f.
\end{align}

In particular, taking $m=k+n$, $t_i:=p_{i}$ for $i=0,\dots k$ and $t_{k+i}=q_{i}$ for $i=0,\dots n$, we have that any partition of $[a,c]\cup[c,b]$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, hence $I_3\le I_1+I_2$, because it is the infimum of a larger set.

To prove $I_3\ge I_1+I_2$, it suffices to think analogously, but using the fact that $$I_3=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\sup_{a=t_0<t_1<\cdots t_m=b}\sum_{i=1}^k \inf_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}f.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. It took me a while to understand the whole thing. I have two questions: 1. In the part where you wrote, $t_{k}+i=q_{i}$ for $i=0,…n$ shouldn't i be from k+1 to n? and 2. Does proving this equality automatically prove the integrability of the function f across the interval [a,b]?

Comment: For 1, $p_{k}=c=q_0$, hence defining twice $t_{k}$ as $p_k$ or $t_{k+0}=q_{0}$ is not a problem.
For 2, yes, it does.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.